# How to make button in tree view clickable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, odoo, odoo-14

I have tree view added in wizard. I made wizard window wider due to higher number of fields.
I have added button to tree view according to these guides:
https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/adding-buttons-to-one2many-list-tree-view-as-one-column-182263

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JsnsaSnH8-U

Simplified form view

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="vendor_connector_purchase_wizard_form">
        <field name="name">vendor.connector.purchase.wizard.form</field>
        <field name="model">vendor.connector.purchase.wizard</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Vendor Connector Purchase Helper">
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $('.modal-dialog').css({'max-width': '50%'});
                        $('.modal-content').css({'max-width': '100%'});
                    });
                </script>
                <group string="Purchase Order Helper Lines">
                    <field name="purchase_order_state" invisible="1" readonly="1"/>
                    <field name="purchase_order_helper_line_ids" mode="tree" nolabel="1" style="width:105%;">
                        <tree string="Purchase Order Lines" create="0" delete="0" editable="bottom">
                            <!-- Other fields removed for simplification -->
                            <field name="price_subtotal" widget="monetary" string="Subtotal"/>
                            <!-- BUTTON IS HERE -->
                            <button name="button_use_candidate" type="object" string="Use Candidate" confirm="Are you sure?" class="btn-success"/>
                        </tree>
                    </field>
                </group>

                <!-- Second group was removed for simplification -->
                <footer>
                    <button name="action_done" string="Done" type="object" class="btn-primary" confirm="Are you Sure?"/>
                    <button string="Cancel" special="cancel" class="btn-secondary" />
                </footer>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

[image]

Result after clicking the button. Python method was never called.
[image]
Both wizard model and wizard lines model have 1,1,1,1 access rights.
Please help.

EDIT:
Button method:

```
def button_use_candidate(self):
    print("button test")
```

Call of the wizard:

```
def action_vendor_connector_purchase_wizard(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    action = self.env["ir.actions.actions"]._for_xml_id(
        "vendor_eshop_connector.vendor_connector_purchase_wizard_wizard_action"
    )
    action["context"] = dict(self.env.context)
    action["context"].update(
        active_id=self.id,
        active_ids=self.ids,
    )
    return action
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of `button_use_candidate` method in the model?

Comment: How did you open the wizard form?

Comment: Without pasting the whole method, what does `button_use_candidate` return ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the JavaScript [_renderButton](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/b1847f32e4f3bbfc2196d71d2f4d5005eaa187a4/addons/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_renderer.js#L591-L607) function, you will find that Odoo disables the button when the record is not saved:

```
$button.prop('disabled', true);
```

Or displays the following message when the `warn` option is passed through options

```
Please click on the "save" button first
```

You can find an example in the manufacturing Order [Components](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/b1847f32e4f3bbfc2196d71d2f4d5005eaa187a4/addons/mrp/views/mrp_production_views.xml#L282) list view

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the button didn't work, was that there were missing values in form. Specifically link to the main wizard from the wizard lines, because I was creating wizard lines inside the main wizard´s `default_get` method and main wizard didn't exist yet.

Solution: Create wizard record beforehand and manually create wizard lines.

```
def action_open_wizard(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    wizard = self.env["vendor.connector.purchase.wizard"].create({"purchase_order_id": self.id})
    create_vals_list = []

    for line in self.order_line:
        create_line_vals = {
            "purchase_order_line_id": line.id,
            "product_qty": line.product_qty,
            "price_unit": line.price_unit,
            "substitute_parent_id": wizard.id, # Main wizard link
        }
        create_vals_list.append((0, False, create_line_vals))
    wizard.write({"purchase_order_helper_line_ids": create_vals_list})

    return {
        "name": "Test Wizard",
        "type": "ir.actions.act_window",
        "res_model": "vendor.connector.purchase.wizard",
        "view_mode": "form",
        "res_id": wizard.id,
        "target": "new",
    }
```

Comment: The reason why the button was disabled is that the record was not saved

Comment: @Kenly you are right.